# Value not bound to input in template

Tags: polymer

For some reason my inputs are blank when binding to my published properties. Any ideas what I need to do? Also do I have to use publish probs to bind to internal templates.

```
<polymer-element name="my-foo.html" noscript>

  <script>

    Polymer('my-element', {

      publish: {

              test: 1,
              foo : {
                baa: 1.000
              }
              },
      // Fires when an instance of the element is created
      created: function () {
      },

    });
  </script>
  <template>
    <form>
        <input  value="{{test}}">
        <input  value="{{foo.baa}}">

    </form>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code:

1. Do not use `noscript` attribute in this case. `noscript` can only be used, if you are leaving the Polymer constructor blank (so you could leave out the `<script>` part, while your element still would be registered). But this is obviously not the case here, so leave out this attribute.
2. Your `name` attribute should be `my-foo`. The extension `.html` is not necessary.
3. While calling the Polymer constructor, you need to provide the same name as in `name` attribute of your polymer element. So here instead of `my-element` you need to write `my-foo`. Or you could place the constructor after the `<template>` block. Then it is not necessary to provide any name.

Here is the jsfiddle and snipped of your corrected code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/knzjhjyd/

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    
<polymer-element name="my-foo">
    <script>
        Polymer('my-foo', {
            publish: {
                test: 1,
                foo: {
                    baa: 1.000
                }
            },
            // Fires when an instance of the element is created
            created: function() {}
        });
    </script>
    <template>
        <form>
            <input value="{{test}}">
            <input value="{{foo.baa}}">
        </form>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<my-foo></my-foo>
```

Comment: so noscript is a generic thing that works for all web components?

Comment: You can use it in any of your polymer-elements, which do not require manipulation through javascript. `noscript` is just an equivalent to including `<script>Polymer();</script>` in your component.